# Will a Mule Flow stop processing a message after some arbitrary default number of exceptions thrown?

Tags: mule

I have a flow that inserts objects in a Mongo database using the Mongo connector, which uses the `MongoClientImpl` provided by the connector.  This client has a line that tries to cast the `_id` to an ObjectId prior to returning that value as a string to the user after the insert has been submitted to the database.  As far as I can tell, this line does not impact whether the object is inserted, but it does throw an exception when trying to cast a string to an ObjectId.

My flow is throwing hundreds of `ClassCastException`s.  It also does not appear to be processing nearly as many inserts as I would expect.  I expect to see tens of thousands, but instead the flow is only inserting 136 documents.

Is there a limit to the number of exceptions that can be thrown and captured by Mule's DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy before the flow will stop processing a given message?

Comment: What do you mean by "stop processing"? Does the flow message source (ie poller/endpoint) stop to provide new events after a certain number of exceptions? Also, what you describe here feels like a bug in the Mongo connector (it should not throw `ClassCastException`s): you probably should report the issue to MuleSoft.

Comment: I thought I had read somewhere that a flow will discontinue processing of a given instance of the flow if a certain number of exceptions are thrown within a given flow.  I'm not entirely clear why only 136 documents are successfully inserted when they do not appear to be any different than the 20 some odd thousand that are not inserted.  I thought I would try to rule out whether there was in fact an arbitrary limit to exceptions thrown in a given run of a flow before trying to figure out what else might be going on.

Comment: I created an issue on GitHub here:  https://github.com/mulesoft/mongo-connector/issues/44  Is that the appropriate space to report the issue?

Comment: To be more clear, I hope, a single message comes into my flow and will be broken up into 20,000+ calls to the mongo connector to insert documents already containing an "_id".  I am wondering whether a flow will stop if it reaches an arbitrary threshold of exceptions while processing this single message.

Comment: It would really help if you could show your flow. Indeed, if you create 20K messages and iterate them in the same flow, all in memory, sure, things can break badly. I'd use several flow with an async queue in between to decouple the stages (And yes it's the right location for Mongo connector issues, it would be great if you could format the exception though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, but you can implement some custom logic and stop the flow. Probably you would need afterwards to manually start it, this is how I would do it:

- Use the object store module, for counting the incidences of a given exception.
- Upon a defined number of incidences stop programatically the flow, one option to do this would be something like `#[groovy:<flowName>.stop()]` given that groovy has direct access to the registry.
- Send an email notification so you can be aware of the errors (specially useful for production).

Comment: Hi Juan, I am facing the same problem mentioned by Gary. My AUDIT flow receives message from JMS inbound-endpoint, and tries to insert Audit record into DB. In some cases where DB is down, catch-exception-strategy consumes the messages, writes to FAILURE queue and throws error logs.
I have seen this problem where 80 errors occurred due to DB connection failure. and then AUDIT flow stopped receiving events from JMS inbound-endpoint. I could see 1465 messages in queue, and it gets loaded up, but the flow is not able to pick those for processing